# Backslashes in command-line argument under Cygwin

Tags: string, perl

I am passing in the full path to a file as a commandline argument in perl. 
For example

```
myscript.pl C:\Dir\myfile.txt
```

In myscript.pl, I have

```
my $full_path = shift;            
print $full_path;
```

When I do this, my output is

```
C:Dirmyfile.txt
```

What I really want is `C:\Dir\myfile.txt`
But when I run my script as

```
myscript.pl 'C:\Dir\myfile.txt'
```

my output is `C:/Dir/myfile.txt`. Now it has forward slashes instead of backslashes. How do I get what I want? (The same text as what was passed in, file path with backslashes)

I need to run be able to run this script on **Cygwin** in a windows environment. Note that the script serves a larger purpose, but what I have posted is the part I am stuck with. The path is something I copy from somewhere else, so I really don't want to do the extra work of replacing backslash with forward slash or spaces.

Comment: For your first example you can escape the backslashes `C:\\Dir\\myfile.txt`. I can't recreate your second example. Are you manipulating `$full_path` in any way?

Comment: Note that `C:/Dir/myfile.txt` and `C:\Dir\myfile.txt` are both valid Windows paths to the same file.

Comment: What's the first line of `myscript.pl`?

Comment: @ikegami What I have posted is the entire script.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I have edited my question. I wonder if it's anything to do with the environment I am running it on.

Comment: I found this link - http://www.hugoestrada.net/node/243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `File::Spec` module.  This simplifies passing parameters to your script, since you don't need to use slashes, and it also makes your application portable across operating systems.

```
use File::Spec;

my $full_path = File::Spec->catfile(@ARGV);
print $full_path, "\n";
```

Example:

```
perl myscript.pl C: Dir myfile.txt
C:\Dir\myfile.txt
```

Alternatively, if you need to use the full path string, then use the following line in place of the above:

```
my $full_path = File::Spec->canonpath($ARGV[0]);
```

Example 2:

```
perl myscript.pl C:\Dir\myfile.txt
```

**--OR--**

```
perl myscript.pl C:/Dir/myfile.txt

C:\Dir\myfile.txt
```

Example 3 (for Cygwin) - surround parameter with single quotes:

```
perl myscript.pl 'C:\Dir\myfile.txt'
C:\Dir\myfile.txt
```

Comment: Yes it works if i have spaces, but doesn't seem to work if I have backslashes. I was wondering if there is a way do this. It's okay even if it isn't portable.

Comment: @Mathai That's the point, you don't need to enter the backslashes.  The module manages the backslashes (or forward slashes) for you, according to the OS on which you're running.

Comment: I copy the path from somewhere else and paste it when I need to run the script. That means I have to do the extra work of removing the slashes and replacing then with spaces.

Comment: @Mathai Ok - got it.  I updated the solution to show that case, as well (see Example 2).

Comment: I just tried that, but I get the same thing with all slashes removed. I wonder if its anything to do with the way I am running the script. This script is run on a cygwin shell in a windows environment.

Comment: @Mathai Yes, I just confirmed your results.  The cygwin shell must be interpreting the slashes before the parameters are passed to the script. It will work from Win cmd or powershell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78944/discussion-between-mathai-and-david).